# How to have 2 input fields with suggestions in sap.m Dialog fragment?

Tags: javascript, sapui5, hana

I have a sap.m Dialog fragment (xml) which needs to have 2 input fields with suggestions.The controller associated with this fragment has a dedicated view and the Model bound in the init method of the controller populates data in the view , not fragment.For each of the input fields, I have a seperate xsjs service that retrieves the data for the corresponding field.The 2 services refer to 2 different tables.How to get the 2 input fields with suggestions from 2 different tables in the same form itself? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Just create a model for each service. Then bind `suggestionItems` to these services using the `model>` prefix:

```
<Input showSuggestion="true" suggestionItems="{model1>/List1}" >
    <suggestionItems>
        <core:Item text="{model1>Name}" />
    </suggestionItems>
</Input>

<Input showSuggestion="true" suggestionItems="{model2>/List2}" >
    <suggestionItems>
        <core:Item text="{model2>Name}" />
    </suggestionItems>
</Input>
```

Comment: Pssst! You should prefix the aggregation with the named model as well ;-) I.e. `<core:Item text="{model1>Name}" />` etc